# Python 2 to Python 3: can't get multiprocessing to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-multiprocessing

I'm moving my code from python 2.7 to python 3.5 and cannot get my multiprocessing code to work, something like the following code. **"somemodule.py" in the same directory as the main script**.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# somemodule is in the same folder as this script
import somemodule

def foo(bar):
    print(bar)
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar = ("alice","bob")
    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)
    pool.map(foo, bar)
    pool.close()
```

The traceback is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    prepare(preparation_data)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
    _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 240, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\hobboy\Documents\project\pool_test3.py", line 2, in <module>
    import somemodule
ImportError: No module named 'somemodule'
```

The code works in the Python Console of Spyder, but not IPython (working with Anaconda3 2.5.0). **The worker processes are unable to import `somemodule` but the main process can**. Is it something to do with `import somemodule` being inadequate, or something else? I've read into the Python 3 import syntax a bit, but I'm still not sure.

I've made a post on the Anaconda community forums but that's more in regards to if it's an issue with Anaconda rather than the code itself.

---

**Additional information:**

**For main process (non worker) for Python 2.7/3.5, `sys.path[0]=''` regardless of console/python version**

What's interesting is that sys.path[0] varies for the worker processes:

**Spyder 2.3.8 (Python 2.7)**

- Python Console: '' (works)
- IPython Console: '' (works)

**Spyder 2.3.8 (Python 3.5)**

- Python Console: 'C:\Users\hobboy\Documents\project' (works)
- IPython Console: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32' (doesn't work)

**However the main (non worker) process for both Python 2 and 3 being `sys.path=''`. Why is sys.path[0] being set differently (and inconsistently) in Python 3**

Comment: where do you put somemodule.py?

Comment: @Yen Sorry I may not have been clear enough, somemodule.py is in the same directory as the script. I've updated the post to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what you get when you add the following code on the very first line of your script:

```
import sys; print(sys.path)
```

The output should include the directory where your "somemodule" is. If it's not listed, you can explicitly manipulate your environment by appending the directory to the sys.path list (careful escaping backslashes) before importing the module.

Another alternative is making sure the python interpreter is run directly from that folder, so that the "working directory" includes somemodule.py.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. 

So according to the docs `sys.path[0]` is the current directory if empty, or the supplied script directory. I created another section **Additional information** which has the `sys.path[0]` of the worker processes in different situations.

Path varies across different consoles and different python versions. This seems really inconsistent, is this intended behaviour or could it be a bug? I haven't yet added the working directory to path as you suggest but I imagine that would work, although it really seems like a workaround in this case.

Comment: @hobboy i think these are implementation-specific details not covered by python spec, so interpreters do their own thing. Manipulating sys.path is very common. Another thing you can do is using relative imports (.somemodule) so that the machinery will always look in the script directory rather than going through sys.path.